# PHP, Sessions, Cookies - something is happening that doesn't allow some users to log in?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

We have about 100 users accessing our website daily.  A majority of them have no issues logging in.  However, once a month we get a call or email ticket with complaints that users just see the login page refresh, with no error messages or anything.

All error messages are sent through the PHP Session cookie, and of course everything after logging in is based off of that session.  The only reason I could think that the page just refreshes HAS to be because they are blocking that session cookie on their local machine...

Now most often the user is on internet explorer, but occationally it even happens with Chrome or Firefox.  I've even had a user (on OSX) who tried Safari, Chrome, FF - and it would NEVER let them log in, the page would just basically refresh.  I had the user add the website as trusted, and still no luck.

It's the worst because I cannot reproduce it from any network or from any browser/computer, ever.

Does anyone know what could be causing something like this?  The site IS forcing SSL (the HTACCESS file redirects to HTTPS).  The site IS forcing the session cookie as HTTP-Only and the Secure flag is also set to TRUE (and these 2 are somewhat recent changes).

I'm unsure what other settings on the server or the PHP instance would be causing something like this, or if it's soley a client-side issue (which it appears to be).  And if it's client side, I'd like to learn the issue and possible solutions to it.

To preempt everyone, no - I cannot share the website URL for debugging because the client would not appreciate that, unfortunately.  Thanks for any help, I'll be happy to answer any question that I can!

Comment: Hire someone who knows what they're doing. We can't help you with theoretical issues and no way to see any code interaction.

Comment: have you tried reproducing the error by changing the time on your local computer? change either time or date and see if that affects anything.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I will be happy to show you code if you have any ideas where to start...?

Comment: "because they blocking that session cookie on their local machine...", Not following that one... maybe session file locking on the server, but on the client?  Also doesn't using 'secure cookies' require HTTPS, confused by "session cookie as HTTP-Only"?

Comment: @ficuscr Well on the client, I figured it could be becauase they don't allow cookies.  But even when I have them add the domain as a trusted site, still no luck.

Comment: My crystal ball says some requests getting routed over HTTP and cookies not being sent because of the secure flag.  I can make more guesses but suggest you debug further / provide more info.

Comment: @ficuscr So would it be possible that a client could visit the site securely (SSL, HTTPS), but for some reason deny the cookie over SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one web server behind a load balancer? And are the PHP sessions stored locally on each web server?  If so it is the load balancer's job to make sure a user keeps going back to the same server on repeated accesses. If something goes wrong, they could get sent to a server where they do not have a session. It could be some intermittent glitch sending users to the wrong server.

Just guessing, because as others noted, we don't really have enough info.

Comment: Hm... Well it's on a virtualized "cloud" server hosted by cloudweb.com.  Just one virtualized machine.

Answer (score 0):

Does your session cookie have a valid name? I've run into this problem in the past where some browsers don't accept a session cookie if it has an invalid name, but other browsers do accept them;

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: I don't define a session name... and never have.  The server defaults to `PHPSESSID`.